# Destroy and restart Activity with Testing Support Library

Tags: android, testing, android-testing, testing-support-library

Using the old JUnit3-style tests in Android, I could do the following to destory and restart an activity:

```
Instrumentation inst = getInstrumentation();
Activity activity = inst.getActivity();
// do something
activity.finish();
Assert.assertTrue(this.activity.isFinishing());
activity = inst.getActivity();
// assert that activity's state is restored
```

How can I accomplish the same thing using the new Testing Support Library? I'm fine with using either Espresso and/or UI Automator or any other mechanism provided by the new library.

**Update:**

I tried the following:

```
Activity activity = activityTestRule.getActivity();
// do something
activity.finish();
Assert.assertTrue(this.activity.isFinishing());
activity = activityTestRule.getActivity();
// assert that activity's state is restored
```

However, it appears that `ActivityTestRule.getActivity()` does not restart the activity.

Comment: I would assume that the `finish()` part should be no different than before. I don't know if `getActivity()`, called on your `ActivityTestRule`, will re-create a destroyed activity or not.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried that and it doesn't seem to restart the activity.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I'm not quite sure what state you're expecting to get restored after a `finish()`. You could try calling `launchActivity()` after the `finish()` and see what happens, though that will create a fresh instance. Or, you could probably add it yourself. [Fork `ActivityTestRule`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/rules/src/main/java/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule.java) and hack away!

Comment: @CommonsWare Perhaps this is an XY problem. The original motivation is to test the following sequence in my app: 1. Start the activity. 2. Enter some data. 3. Destroy the activity, triggering `onSaveInstanceState()`. 4. Restore the activity with the previous state. 5. Assert that the previously entered data is still in the correct views. --- So is there a better way to test this?

Comment: "Perhaps this is an XY problem" -- um, well, I'm male, so that's my chromosome pair, if that's what you mean. :-) "Destroy the activity, triggering onSaveInstanceState()" -- `onSaveInstanceState()` is not called when the activity is destroyed. It is called because the activity undergoes a configuration change. `finish()` should not be triggering `onSaveInstanceState()`. "So is there a better way to test this?" -- you could try `UIAutomation.setRotation()` and see if that triggers `onSaveInstanceState()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare [What is an XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @CommonsWare From what I understand, an orientation change will cause the activity to be destroyed. Is that incorrect?

Comment: "What is an XY problem?" -- yes, but my interpretation is funny! "an orientation change will cause the activity to be destroyed" -- correct. However, the inverse is not true: destroying an activity does not cause a configuration change. `onSaveInstanceState()` is tied to configuration changes (plus some task-related scenarios, but there only for non-destroyed activities). `onSaveInstanceState()` is not tied to being destroyed for other reasons.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice but can u say pleas how u resolve this problem in espresso tests?

Comment: @Morozov I have not had the time to verify any of the answers since I asked this question.

Answer (score 8):

As @CommonsWare mentioned, a custom rule is pretty useful. Here's my simple solution (many improvements are possible, but this is just a quick framework that can be built on):

```
public class ControlledActivityTestRule<T extends Activity> extends ActivityTestRule<T> {
    public ControlledActivityTestRule(Class<T> activityClass) {
        super(activityClass, false);
    }

    public ControlledActivityTestRule(Class<T> activityClass, boolean initialTouchMode) {
        super(activityClass, initialTouchMode, true);
    }

    public ControlledActivityTestRule(Class<T> activityClass, boolean initialTouchMode, boolean launchActivity) {
        super(activityClass, initialTouchMode, launchActivity);
    }

    public void finish() {
        finishActivity();
    }

    public void relaunchActivity() {
        finishActivity();
        launchActivity();
    }

    public void launchActivity() {
        launchActivity(getActivityIntent());
    }
}
```

Note, if you do it like this, this class needs to be in the package `android.support.test.rule` to access the package private method `ActivityTestRule#finishActivity`. Then in your test case, implement this rule:

```
@Rule
public ControlledActivityTestRule<TestFountainPreferenceActivity> actRule = new ControlledActivityTestRule<>(TestFountainPreferenceActivity.class);
```

Then in your individual test case, call `actRule.finish()` and `actRule.launchActivity()` to kill and restart it. Or you can call `actRule.relaunchActivity()` if you don't need to do anything in between killing it and starting it up again. Note, you can pass the third parameter `false` to delay starting the activity if you have initial startup, and then call `actRule.launchActivity()` to get it going, but you will loose access to some of the built in handles such as `#afterActivityLaunched` and `#afterActivityFinished()`.

Comment: That's correct, #finishActivity is package protected, so I expose it with the provided #finish method.

Comment: is there any way to extend it so that recreated activity receives Bundle from onSaveInstanceState?

Answer (score 2):

As JCricket and djunod says the way to do it is creating a custom rule. The problem that I faced with their solutions is that the method finishActivity is package protected and you can use it in your custom test rule.

This is my solution:

```
public class RelaunchActivityRule<T extends Activity> extends ActivityTestRule<T> {

  public RelaunchActivityRule(Class<T> activityClass) {
    super(activityClass,false);
  }

  public RelaunchActivityRule(Class<T> activityClass, boolean initialTouchMode) {
    super(activityClass, initialTouchMode,true);
  }

  public RelaunchActivityRule(Class<T> activityClass, boolean initialTouchMode,
      boolean launchActivity) {
    super(activityClass, initialTouchMode, launchActivity);
  }

  @Override protected void afterActivityFinished() {
    super.afterActivityFinished();
    launchActivity(getActivityIntent());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JCricket's answer worked for me once I added a sleep in there...

```
package android.support.test.rule;

public class ControlledActivityTestRule<T extends Activity> extends ActivityTestRule<T> {
    public ControlledActivityTestRule(Class<T> activityClass) {
        super(activityClass, false);
    }

    public ControlledActivityTestRule(Class<T> activityClass, boolean initialTouchMode) {
        super(activityClass, initialTouchMode, true);
    }

    public ControlledActivityTestRule(Class<T> activityClass, boolean initialTouchMode, boolean launchActivity) {
        super(activityClass, initialTouchMode, launchActivity);
    }

    public void finish() {
        finishActivity();
    }

    public void relaunchActivity(int seconds) {
        finishActivity();
        sleep(seconds);
        launchActivity();
        sleep(seconds);
    }

    public void launchActivity() {
        launchActivity(getActivityIntent());
    }

    public void sleep(int seconds) {
        if (seconds > 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was then able to do a test with iterations:

```
@Rule
public ControlledActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ControlledActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

@Test
public void testOAA310() {
    int count = 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        testCaseOAA310();
        mActivityRule.relaunchActivity(5);
    }
}

void testCaseOAA310() { /* ... blah blah blah... */ }
```

Comment: Why does `testOAA310()` call itself? This appears to be an infinite recursion.

Comment: testOAA310 calls testCaseOAA310... not itself.

Comment: What is the difference in those method names?

Comment: OIC...test vs testCase... that seems like a poor distinction because it was not immediately obvious to me

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what was failing that you need to put a sleep in? It's not horrible since it's in testing, but i hate putting in sleeps because it breaks the trust of a proper testing scenario. I had some initial problems with synchronicity, but usually traced it back to some other coding error that left something active that should have been killed.

Comment: I believe getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync(); would be prefferable alternative to sleep

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a custom rule. Call `launchActivity(getActivityIntent())` in `afterActivityFinished` method, it will restart the activity after finish.

```
public class RestartActivityRule<T extends Activity> extends ActivityTestRule<T> {

    public RestartActivityRule(Class<T> activityClass) {
        super(activityClass,false);
    }

    public RestartActivityRule(Class<T> activityClass, boolean initialTouchMode) {
        super(activityClass, initialTouchMode,true);
    }

    public RestartActivityRule(Class<T> activityClass, boolean initialTouchMode,
      boolean launchActivity) {
        super(activityClass, initialTouchMode, launchActivity);
    }

    @Override protected void afterActivityFinished() {
        super.afterActivityFinished();
        launchActivity(getActivityIntent());
    }
}
```