# When running espresso tests, app resumes instead of restarting

Tags: android, ui-testing, android-espresso

When I run multiple espresso tests, I find that the app does not restart but starts from the same location that it is left off. How to make it start from the beginning everytime

Comment: This answer can be useful for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35306423/destroy-and-restart-activity-with-testing-support-library/36779019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [Android Test Orchestrator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner.html#using-android-test-orchestrator). It will clear all data and restart Instrumentation between each test.

Add to app Gradle:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
   ...
   testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }

  testOptions {
    execution 'ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
  }
}

dependencies {
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
  androidTestUtil 'com.android.support.test:orchestrator:1.0.1'
}
```

And then run it as follows:

> ./gradlew connectedCheck